# While loop with precision as condition

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, while-loop

Is it possible to do a while loop in C++ until a decimal reaches a certain precision? I want to do a long calculation for arctan and then pi and I want the loop to run until pi is calculated to the 10th decimal place using the formula pi=4(arctan (1.0)). I'm manually calculating arctan using the taylor series formula. I know there are built in functions for these calculations but this is a homework assignment so I have to do it this way. I'm not looking for the solution to the problem, just whether or not a loop using precision is possible. Thanks!

Edit:

I'm still stuck with this! I can't come up with a proper argument for the while loop, even after going over everybody's hints. Really need help. Here's the code I have come up with:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 int i;
 long double result;
 long double pi;
 int y=3;
 int loopcount=0;
 long double precision;

   cout<<"Start\n";

   result=1-(pow(1,y)/y);

  do
    {
     y=y+2;
     result=result+(pow(1,y)/y);
     y=y+2;
     result=result-(pow(1,y)/y);

      pi=4*(result);
      precision=(pi*(pow(10,11))/10);

      loopcount++;
    }
  while(//This is the problem!);

  cout<<"Final Arctan is:"<<endl;
     cout<<setprecision(20)<<result<<endl;
  cout<<"Final Pi is:"<<endl;
       cout<<setprecision(9)<<pi1<<endl;
  cout<<"Times looped:"<<endl;
       cout<<loopcount<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fitting homework for Pi Day. 8v)

Comment: Nice reading here: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Nice link BlackBear very informative material there

Comment: I think **[http://ideone.com/PYWpq](http://ideone.com/PYWpq)** should be the missing link: basically, ensure that the significant part of the result doesn't change anymore. Note that I didn't care about efficiency

Comment: Sehe, that code works however it's not looping past 70906 times. The idea is right but the code is slightly flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can figure out the precision by checking the improvement over the previous iterations. If the 10th decimal place gets stable, break the loop.

to get the kth decimal digit of `n`, multiply it by 10 to the power of `k` and get the least significant digit. For example, to get the 2nd decimal digit 7 out of 3.47, multiply by 100 to get 347 and get the 7 by `347 % 10`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? How do I know if the 10th decimal place is 'stable'? I'm completely new to this and I'm struggling with the floating points so I need some hand holding :)

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain a variable with the result from the last loop, then loop until the difference between them is in an acceptable range.

Edit: removed the code snippet for homework

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least sort of. Usually in a case like this, you don't really look for absolute precision (after all, if you're computing Pi, using a pre-known value of Pi to decide when you're done kind of defeats the purpose).

Instead, most computations like this get progressively closer to the goal, and for each iteration, the change in the value gets progressively smaller. You look at that change in value, and when *it* gets small enough, you consider the value close enough, and exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

With regard specifically to breaking out of the loop, the answer is of course, yes.  There are many ways to do it.

I would pursue comparing the truncated value to the actual value.

For example:
while (myValue <= Truncate(myValue, precision)) will break when myValue is greater than myValue truncated to one less order of precision.  Remember that adding an order of precision makes the number greater (1.1 > 1)

The special sauce is in the Truncate function, this should return the value truncated to whatever order of precision you decide. For example Truncate(1.23456, 3) should return 1.234 (hint:  1.23 * 10 == 12.3)

Comment: Will this not require that I know the 10th decimal place of pi though? The point of this exercise is that the computer should do the calculation for you. Looking up the pi value defeats the purpose

Comment: No definitely not.  Remember that by adding an order of precision the number gets larger.  1 < 1.1, 1.1 < 1.11, etc.  I'll clean up my answer a bit, but I'm going to try not and give too much away.

Comment: Yeah that's much clearer now I see what you're saying. That's a nice way of doing it I'm going to make an attempt at this thanks.